# The following is my matplotlib but i think there's something wrong in it

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax2=fig.add_axes([0.2,0.5,0.4,0.4])
ax1.set_xlim([0,100])
ax1.set_ylim([0,10000])
ax2.set_xlim([20,22])
ax2.set_ylim([30,50])
ax1.set_ylabel('Z')
ax1.set_xlabel('X')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2000))
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(20))
ax2.set_ylabel('Y')
ax2.set_xlabel('X')
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.5))
```

This is printing out the following plot.

[image]

Comment: I think you got your tickers and axes mixed up. Flip each instance of `xaxis` and `yaxis`.

Comment: You're making 10000/20 y-ticks on the ax1 (which works out to be 500 ticks) and 20/0.5 y-ticks on ax2 (which works out to be 40 ticks). That's quite a lot of information to display.

Comment: @dm2 Yes thank you, silly mistake

Comment: @BigBen My bad, silly me. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as caused by a typo / not reproducible, as the OP has acknowledged the mistake pointed out by @BigBen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed tick locators, adjusted subplot positioning, organized code a bit, hid spines, added dashed y grid, increased tick label font sizes.

[image]

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.575,0.55,0.3,0.3])

ax1.set_xlim([0,100])
ax1.set_ylim([0,10000])
ax1.set_xlabel('X', fontweight='bold')
ax1.set_ylabel('Z', rotation=0, fontweight='bold')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(20))
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1000))
ax1.grid(axis='y', dashes=(8,3), color='gray', alpha=0.3)

ax2.set_xlim([20,22])
ax2.set_ylim([30,50])
ax2.set_xlabel('X', fontweight='bold')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y', rotation=0, fontweight='bold')
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.5))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))

for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    [ax.spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['top','right']]
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=12, left=False, bottom=False)
```

Comment: Side note: "adjusted subplot positioning, ... hid spines, added dashed y grid, increased tick label font size". It seems like you answered questions that OP didn't have.

Comment: Is that poor form? I'm new-ish here. I just like making plots look nice :)

Comment: Perhaps, IMO. (the question will probably be closed as a typo, at which point, not worth an answer).